# Performing multiple inserts using AsyncQueryHandler android

Tags: android, database, asynchronous, insert

I want to perform multiple inserts using AsyncQueryHandler.
Is it possible?
As waiting for one event to be completed before starting a new insert is pointless.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Or the option is, to use a AsyncTask with a loop of ContentValue.

BR,
Jayshil

Comment: There's potentially the option to send a separate token for each `startInsert()`, and only actually do something in `onInsertComplete()` once all the tokens are returned, this too seems sub-optimal though, so a proper answer would be great.

Comment: I currently did using a Asynctask by passing a ArrayList of contentValues.

Comment: @Thorbear The only problem i see that it may cause multiple thread error on the db. Where simultaneous calls to the same database may cause errors.